# How to calculate a fiscal month from middle of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a one month range from 2-15-13 to 2-28-13, but Dateadd(mm,-1,'2-28-13') would return 1-15-13 to 1-28-13, I want it to end at the proper end of month, i.e, 1-31-13. Any help is appreciated.

**(edit/update)**

I would like to make it more clear:

```
declare  @Lastmonth_StartDate datetime,
         @Lastmonth_EndDate datetime,
         @StartDate datetime = '2/15/13',
         @EndDate datetime = '2/28/13'

set @Lastmonth_EndDate=DATEADD(m,-1,@EndDate)
set @Lastmonth_StartDate =DATEADD(m,-1,@StartDate)
select @Lastmonth_StartDate, @Lastmonth_EndDate
```

Instead of jan 28, I would like jan 31 for `Lastmonth_EndDate`, and if start dates are 2/1/13 - 2/15/13 I would like `Lastmonth_EndDate` to be the 15th of the previous month.

-- Edit 6/18

I am trying to use IF or CASE to do the job but am not that good, any lead please?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111892/sql-how-to-determine-if-date-month-date-contains-29-30-or-31?rq=1

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Using 2008R2, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the end of a year-month, add one month to the first of that year-month, then subtract 1 day.  The rest is details.

Comment: if i do that, my result is not as expected if start dates are 2-1-13 to 2-15-13 for example. thanks.

Comment: If 2-1-13 is Jan 2nd, then you didn't add one month the first of the year month, you added it to the 2nd.

Comment: No Dan, its feb 1st.  What I want is not so exact one previous month: if i pass 2-1-13 to 2-15-13 i want 1-1-13 to 1-15-13, and if i pass 2-15-13 to 2-28-13 i want 1-15-13 to 1-31-13. see if you can help please. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the syntax you use I believe you use SQL Server, for SQL Server you can do as follows:

Start of the period:

```
Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(7),DateAdd(m, 0, '2-15-13'),121) + '-01 00:00:00.000', 121)
```

End of period:

```
DateAdd(d, -1, Convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(7),DateAdd(m, 1, '2-28-13'),121) + '-01 23:59:59.997', 121)))
```